# Python ошибки с записью в файл txt

Tags: python, файлы, словари

У меня есть функция:

```
def writer_file(num):
    stat = {'2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0}
    stat[str(num)] = 1

    f = open('new.txt', 'r')
    file_stat = literal_eval(f.read())
    z = {k: stat[k] + file_stat[k] for k in stat}
    f.close()
    w = open('new.txt', 'w')
    w.write(str(z))
    w.close()
    return True
```

**Что должна делать функция:**
Она получает число(int) - num,
Дальше записывает num в словарь stat,
Следующий шаг - взять из файла 'text.new' старый словарь(строку, которую потом превратит в словарь),
И просуммировать значения ключей нового словаря stat со старым взятым из файла 'text.new'
В финале - записать суму опять в файл.

**Ошибка по типу:**

> Added new number Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\parsing_csgorun\main.py", line 87, in 
> writer_file(2)   File "D:\parsing_csgorun\main.py", line 21, in writer_file
> file_stat = literal_eval(f.read())   File "C:\Users\vital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ast.py",
> line 62, in literal_eval
> node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')   File "C:\Users\vital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ast.py",
> line 50, in parse
> return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,   File "", line 0
>
> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

**Update**

> А что вы первоначально записали в файл?
> Забыл, вот:

```
{'2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что вы первоначально записали в файл? У меня всё работает, если не забыть записать в файл первоначальное состояние:

```
z = {'2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0}
w = open('new.txt', 'w')
w.write(str(z))
w.close()

writer_file(6)
writer_file(2)
writer_file(6)
```

Вывод по команде `!cat new.txt`:

```
{'2': 1, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 2, '7': 0, '8': 0}
```

Если же у вас первоначальный файл просто пустой, то нужно будет несколько поменять логику работы программы, чтобы обойти этап чтения в функции при первом вызове.

Comment: Фак-ап))) 
Было же в файле, я обновил вопрос что было изначально
Я просто удалил или не сохранил)
Спасибо)